# Update a document in a array by array inner document's id, but if that id's document does not exists in array create one with that Id in mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I have a problem. I have a Document the structure is--

```
{
   _id : ObjectId("5da2de41a6889c3d9893270c"),
   marksAndMetas: [
   {st_id: 1, name: "x", mark: 23 },
   {st_id: 2, name: "y", mark: 24 }
  ]

}
```

I want to update a **document** in `marksAndMetas` array by `st_id` if document with same `st_id` exists.
But if not exists I will push a document with that `st_id` into `marksAndMetas`

Answer (score -1):

You can achieve that using below query

```
db.getCollection('inventory').update({"marksAndMetas.st_id":1},{$set:{"marksAndMetas.$.name":"z"}})
```